# Show that convergence and infimum-supremum are the same.

Tags: convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, continuity, supremum-and-infimum

Suppose $K$ is a metric space. Let $f : K \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \cup \{ -\infty,\infty \}$ be an extended real-valued function defined on $K.$

Show that the following is true.

For each $x \in K,$

$\max \{ L \in [-\infty,\infty]: \exists x_n \rightarrow x, f(x_n)\rightarrow L \} = \inf \{ \sup_{y \in U}f(y) : U \text{ is a neighbourhood of }x \}.$

The equality above appears in page $4032$ of this [paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1996-348-10/S0002-9947-96-01719-9/S0002-9947-96-01719-9.pdf).

My approach:

Let $x_n$ be a sequence converges to $x$ such that $f(x_n)$ converges to $L$. For each open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, we have $x_n \in U.$ For this $U$, we have $f(x_n) \leq \sup_{y \in U}f(y).$ Then I stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One direction is already done by you, as for any sequence $\{x_n\}$ converging to $x$ we have that for each neighborhood $U$ of $x$, there is an $N_U$ such that for all $n>N_U$, $x_n\in U$ and so $f(x_n)\leq \sup_{y\in U}\,f(y)$.

For the other direction, we will construct a sequence converging to $x$ whose images converge to $\inf \left\{ \sup_{y \in U}\,f(y)\,:\, U \text{ is a neighborhood of }x \right\}$ as then we so that the above upper bound is attained and so is the maximum of the given set.

The first thing to notice is that $K$ is a metric space and so that $K$ is a $C1$ space, i.e., there is a decreasing sequence of neigborhoods of $x$ $\{V_m\}$ such that for each $m$, $V_m\supseteq V_{m+1}$ and such that for every neighborhood $U$ of $x$ there is some $m_U$ such that $V_{m_U}\subseteq U$. For instance, just take the sequence of open balls $\{B(x,1/m)\}$.

Then, as we have $\sup_{y\in U}\,f(y)\geq \sup_{y\in V_{m_U}}\,f(y)$ (since $V_{m_U}\subseteq U$), we obtain
$$\inf \left\{ \sup_{y \in U}\,f(y)\,:\, U \text{ is a neighborhood of }x \right\}=\inf_m \left\{ \sup_{y \in V_m}\,f(y)\right\}\text{.}$$
Hence we can just work with the sequence of neighbohoods $\{V_m\}$.

For each $m$, we can find a sequence $\{x_{m,n}\}_n$ inside $V_m$ such that $\{f(x_{m,n})\}_n$ is a monotonous sequence such that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\,f(x_{m,n})=\sup_{y\in V_m}\,f(y)$. Then, take for each $m$, the $z_m:=x_{m,n_m}$ such that
$$\sup_{y \in V_m}\,f(y)-\frac{1}{m}\leq f(z_m)\leq \sup_{y \in V_m}\,f(y)$$
and then we have that $\{z_m\}$ is a sequence such that $z_m\to x$, as for all $m>m_0$, $z_m\in V_m\subseteq V_{m_0}$, and such that $\lim_{m\to \infty}\,f(z_m)=\lim_{m\to\infty}\sup_{y \in V_m}\,f(y)$ by the above inequality. Now, as $\{V_m\}$ is decreasing, $\{\sup_{y \in V_m}\,f(y)\}_m$ is decreasing and so it converges to $\inf_m \left\{ \sup_{y \in V_m}\,f(y)\right\}$, i.e.,
$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\sup_{y \in V_m}\,f(y)=\inf_m\sup_{y \in V_m}\,f(y)\text{.}$$
Hence $\{z_m\}$ is the desired sequence converging to $x$ whose images converge to the wanted upper bound.

Comment: Nice proof. A question: How do you get $\inf \left\{ \sup_{y \in U}\,f(y)\,:\, U \text{ is a neighborhood of }x \right\}=\inf_m \left\{ \sup_{y \in V_m}\,f(y)\right\}$?

Comment: "$\geq$" follows from $\sup_{y\in V_{m_U}}\,f(y)\leq\sup_{y\in U}\,f(y)$ as $V_{m_U}$ is contained in $U$. "$\leq$" follows because the RHS set is a subset of the LHS set.

Comment: For the first paragraph, am I right to say that $f(x_n) \leq \inf_{ x \in U} \sup_{ y\in U}f(y)?$

Comment: @Idonknow The last term doesn't make sense.

Comment: why the last term doesn't make sense? Both are numbers.

Comment: @Idonknow Now I got it you quantify the infimum with respect $U$ and not $x$. Sorry. The reason why you cannot write directly $f(x_n) \leq \inf_{U\ni x} \sup_{ y\in U}f(y)$ is because 1) you should indicate for which $n$ it does hold and 2) it may not hold for arbitrary $n$ as we have $f(x_n) \leq  \sup_{ y\in U}f(y)$ only for $n>n_U$  where $n_U$ can go to infinity as it range over all $U\ni x$.